# Quasar - adding a Pinia Store creates a VUex store

Tags: quasar, pinia

I can't solve this issue, always going back to the same issue. When I run **quasar new store stores** it creates files that are no match to a current quasar documentation, containing files like for vuex store:

```
store
   stores
      - action.js
      - getters.js
      - index.js
      - mutation.js
      - state.js
   - index.js
```

But expected to have pinia and all files related to pinia:

```
.
└── src/
    └── stores/       # Pinia
        ├── index.js  # Pinia initialization
        ├── <store>   # Pinia store...
        └── <store>   # Pinia store...
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client-profile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Lambda Client Profile App",
  "productName": "Client Profile",
  "author": "Branislav Papulin <branislav.papulin@nephelesolutions.com>",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "build": "quasar build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-components": "^1.9.6",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.3.3",
    "@quasar/cli": "^1.3.2",
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.14.1",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.12",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1117.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "quasar": "^2.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.22.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

And in node_modules I can see pinia is installed, but when I run quasar info I don't see it installed:

```
Operating System - Linux(5.4.0-100-generic) - linux/x64
NodeJs - 16.13.0

Global packages
NPM - 8.4.1
yarn - 1.22.4
@quasar/cli - 1.3.2
@quasar/icongenie - Not installed
cordova - Not installed

Important local packages
quasar - 2.7.3 -- Build high-performance VueJS user interfaces (SPA, PWA, SSR, Mobile and Desktop) in record time
@quasar/app - 3.3.3 -- Quasar Framework local CLI
@quasar/extras - 1.14.1 -- Quasar Framework fonts, icons and animations
eslint-plugin-quasar - Not installed
vue - 3.2.37 -- The progressive JavaScript framework for building modern web UI.
vue-router - 4.0.16
vuex - Not installed
electron - Not installed
electron-packager - Not installed
electron-builder - Not installed
```

Should be pinia included as well.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve this problem?

Comment: Interesting, I'm having a similar but Opposite issue?

I have both store types in my app now (I want to create a new Pinia store before refactoring all my VueX stores) and in Quasar's Webpack utils it correctly types it as a Pinia store, but it causes typing issues because now Typescript infers that all stores are Pinia e.g. Argument of type 'Pinia' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Store<StateInterface>'

yarn.lock:
"@quasar/app-webpack@^3.5.7":
quasar@^2.7.1:
  version "2.7.5"

But I didn't use Quasar New so take my comment with a pinch of salt...

Answer (score 1):

Same issue... tried updating quasar, cli, and pinia. I can even build a new clean quasar app with npm init quasar and select Pinia and it then creates a stores path but quasar new store storename still uses vuex... I can't even get vuex to uninstall (os x platform with vs code). quasar info still shows it.

The only solution I found is to add the path to stores in quasar.config.js:

```
sourceFiles: {
  store: "src/stores/index",
},
```

I believe this has broken in the last couple months because I have been using pinia in my project without issue and then suddenly it couldn't find it in the "stores" path and was expecting index.js to be in a "store" directory instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to not only remove the `vuex` entry in the **package.json** but actually uninstall it.
In the project folder, call:

**yarn: uninstall vuex**

```
yarn remove vuex
```

**npm: uninstall vuex**

```
npm uninstall vuex
```

This will also remove it from the **package.json**.
After uninstalling I could also remove the `sourceFiles` entry in **quasar.config.js**.

Result in console:

```
quasar new store demo
App • Generated store: src\stores\demo.js
```